# SafeShell::CommandFailedException: in pdftk

Tags: linux, ruby-on-rails-5, apple-m1, pdftk

I am getting `SafeShell::CommandFailedException: Shell command ["/opt/homebrew/bin/pdftk"` error while executing  `pdftk.fill_form 'public/data.pdf', pdf_name_with_path, data, :flatten => true`

Earlier it was working when i was using pdftk, now i just installed java-pdftk using `arch -arm64 brew install pdftk-java` and it stopped working.

I already updated the pdftk path after installing it.

I am using above in `RubyonRails5` and gem `pdf-forms`

I am using `Mac M1(12.3.1)`

Comment: hi Chakreshwar did you resolve this? I left you a comment on another forum but not sure it triggered an email to you, i hope this one does.  thanks for any help with this, exact same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem which I was making here is that I accidently deleted the folder(`tmp/pdf`) where I was generating the pdf. So, as per this question, the path at `pdf_name_with_path` was not a valid path. I updated the path and it works.

But yes, the `pdftk` error was misleading us.